# using SQL Server 2016 inside vs2015 is this normal?

Tags: windows-10-desktop, sql-server-2016-express

I'm trying to learn asp.net, and suddenly in the free online course SQL was used.

I found SQL Server 2016 to be free for developers and so I installed it.
Eventually i managed to create manually a simple database, and put some values in it, well not bad for a first day SQL experience.

However I get some strange errors and i begin to doubt if this database does respond as currently I'm looking at visual studio and see this:

[image]

Now I am aware that VS2015 has a dark theme, things are usually black.
But I am kind of worried that those dark icons are not themed but some kind of error.

I installed it on windows 10 64bit, the only warning i got was that i should update my windows defender firewall, but well in the end i could create a database, but I'm not really sure if this correctly working. should those icons all be black, should dark cross icons exist, is there a way to make sure that VS2015 can access the SQL Server database?

As for one error I cannot currently delete the table "Table" with black cross symbol giving me the feeling that something is wrong, (but i an edit the "SQLCountries" database)

should i set something specific open in firewall that I'm not aware of
or is there some check to see if it is still running

Answer (score 0):

well to anyone out there seeing dark crosses is not OK.
it was caused by network issues (cable unplugged) while i was on wifi
disconnected network card caused SQL to be active but it didnt allow for connection over wifi.